# Jenkinsfile Logic Flow

Tags: json, groovy, jenkins-pipeline

I am trying to create a Jenkins Logic Workflow using a Jenkinsfile. However, I have a little knowledge on how the Groovy Language works and here's what I wanted to achieve.

I have environment.json file and I want my Jenkins to check the value of Weight Traffic. If the value of trafficWeight = '1.0' then the Jenkins will switch/swap the value of SOURCE_GREEN and SOURCE_BLUE, and trafficWeight will be changed to 0.0. Lastly, the Jenkins will output the updated environment.json file and push back to bitbucket via git command.

This is my initial code:

```
stage('Last Stage') {
    steps {
        def getTraffic(jsonFile){
        def fileContent = readFile "${environment.json}"
        Map jsonContent = (Map) new JsonSlurper().parseText(fileContent)
        traffic = jsonContent.get("WEIGHT_TRAFFIC")
    }
```

This is the screenshot of environment.json:

[image]

Any help will be appreciated. Thanks

Comment: So what have you tried so far? Seem like you look for someone to code for you.

Comment: I have my initial code but I cannot proceed yet because I am not familiar on the syntax. Anyway, I am reading tutorial articles of Unix Command.

Comment: I would probably start with this: https://jenkins.io/doc/pipeline/steps/pipeline-utility-steps/#readjson-read-json-from-files-in-the-workspace